# Ubuntu 20.04, Grub BIOS entries, PC does not know what to do

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

Since approximately 2 Weeks the PC stuck during Boot.
No modification by me, only automatically updates confirmed.

Dual System : Windows + Ubuntu 20.04, grub menu, first entry Ubuntu.
After switch On PC. four possibilities :

1. Blue screen : Windows must be repaired ... (no user action)
2. Message : Reboot and select proper boot device or Insert boot Media ... (only a Hard-Reset does help) (no user action)
3. "Normal" grub menu, no user action, and after a short time, PC boots to :
   "error: failure reading sector 0x2fc50d00 from 'hd0' press any key to continue...!
4. "Normal" grub menu (1. Ubuntu ...), select something, see below

If I choose Ubuntu, get login screen, and Ubuntu works.

If I choose Windows, get Win login screen, and Win works.

Since approximately 2 Weeks I have three UEFI Bios entries.

Is it a good Idea by Grub, to write anything to Bios ?

(Beneath, this question written  : If i choose Ubuntu ...)

Comment: Are both systems UEFI boot? And did Windows do an update? That often turns fast start up back on, and then grub cannot boot Windows. Or if Windows needs chkdsk, grub cannot boot it. And Windows may update UEFI which can change some settings back to defaults. I have to keep a list, but my system is so old, that it does not auto update UEFI firmware. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Both are UEFI, the link : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/F5YzqCjnm4/. I did change the SATA port, because it was not possible anymore to get the Grub menu (from 3G to 6G port), currently the system does work without problems.